# Views listing of nodes and node title as exposed filter

Tags: nodes, ajax, views

When I started this view I thought it would be simple… But it's not.

I've an "Office" content type and a view (block) where are listed my "Office" nodes as teaser.

First of all it could be great if the result should be sorted with AJAX, but it's only an option.
I would like an exposed dropdown list filter with all the nodes title of my "Office" content type. But it seems I could only expose an input search field.

I already looked at [BEF](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and several posts here but I didn't find a clear solution.

Comment: I think that you will go to make this programmatically, because I never had seen this.

Comment: In the field settings, there's a check box at the very bottom with something like "views exposed" that lets you use the field as an exposed filter. I'm not sure though as I think the question is a little unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution with [Views Selective Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters). :)

By added a "Regions" field in my content type I've been able to get only the regions with results exposed as a filter in my views.